# Wi-Fi network setup

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

I am a novice in networking and I'm trying to establish a home network which allows internet and file sharing.

**What I have done**

I have connected my broadband internet connection to my Wi-Fi router and I can access the internet on my PC, laptop, mobile devices, and TouchPad after settings some IP settings. Since I have set a wireless security password, whenever I connect a device to the network the first time I'm required to enter a password.

To connect all devices to my Wi-Fi router, I set the following settings:

1. Gateway IP address to Wi-Fi router address, for example 1.2.3.254
2. Device IP address between 1.2.3.100 - 1.2.3.253
3. Subnet mask address 255.255.255.0

When I enter the gateway/Wi-Fi router address in a browser, it shows me DNS and some IP address information like below

[image: WAN status]

**Questions**

1. When I check the WAN status, as shown in above image, do these addresses belong to my ISP?
2. If I enable file sharing, would it be visible on the internet?
3. Can I use my mobile phone, TouchPad, or a Wi-Fi USB dongle to increase Wi-Fi router signal strength so I can connect other devices which are far from the Wi-Fi router?
4. Can I share files between my laptop and my PC, even when I have my PC connected to the router via a LAN cable, and my laptop is connected via Wi-Fi?.
5. My TV has a USB port but it is not Wi-Fi-capable by default. Can I connect it to my PC to play movies/songs through a Wi-Fi USB dongle?

* I think my TV cannot be connected since I can't install a Wi-Fi USB dongle driver on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Only your IP address is owned by your ISP, the others are local and are only relevant to your local network.
2. Not unless you port forward, so keep your ports closed and your firewall up and you won't have a problem.
3. Not really, unless you have a PC connected with an Ethernet cable. You can plug the wifi dongle into that and set it up as an access point using 'Internet Connection Sharing'.
4. Yes, anything that is on the same network.
5. Never heard of that, unless you have a smart TV that usb port is for servicing. If it is a smart tv then you will only be able to watch movies and play music thats on the USB stick.

Comment: **1)** router address is 192.167.122.254. Connected devices addresses are 192.167.122.xxx. But WAN status is showing 10.27.xx.xx. why so? **2)** I guess touchpad/mobile phones can work as computer so they can be used in the same way yuo suggested in 3rd point. Let me search it. If some software or setings is in your mind for android device, plz suggest.